# Building GMP 6.1.0 on 64 bit Windows 7 (msys2/mingw64): configure fails due to mp_limb_t is not 64 bits

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, gmp, msys2

I try to build GMP on my Windows 7 64 bit computer, so I run the `config.guess` and get `k10-pc-msys`. (I use msys2 and mingw64)

Then I ran

```
./configure --prefix=/c/gmp-6.1.0 --build=k10-pc-msys --enable-cxx
```

But this quits with this error

> ```
> checking size of mp_limb_t... 4
> configure: error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 32 bits, but the assembler code
> in this configuration expects 64 bits.
> ```

So I ran the config again with an additional `ABI=64` (thinking to force `mp_limb_t` to be 64 bit), but this ends in the same error. After this I tried to add `CC="g++"` (thinking `--enable-cxx` needs `g++`), but once again I get this error.

I googled a lot about this and found one issue reported to [juliaLang on GitHub](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13206) that looks close to my problem, but the solution seems not to work for me, since I'm not using Julia.

Does anyone know this error and found a way to fix it?

**Notice**: I see that msys2 already has installed and I can use it. But the runtime of my program increased by about 70% only from building NTL with the installed GMP from msys2. I think this is because it was not build for my computer so it is not optimized at all.

**Edit**: Even without any settings (just `./configure --prefix=/c/gmp-6.1.0`) does quit with the same error.

**Background**: I want to use the thread safe build of [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/). But to build NTL thread safe, I have to use GMP.

Comment: A bigger version of GMP might be because they did a FAT build (one for each processor variant, put all together). Note that I cannot reproduce your issue. My assumption is that either you were not starting from a clean directory, or you had something in your environment that interfered.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I assure you, that I started from a clean directory. But it is possible that something interfered. My `PATH` contains only one path to a compiler, namely `C:/mysys64/mingw64/bin`. So I'm not sure what else can interfere.

Comment: Could you put the complete config.log somewhere? (say from configure run with no arguments)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to find differences with my setup. For now, the most obvious is that you haven't updated in a bit (`pacman -Syu` I believe, but don't run it without checking).

Comment: @MarcGlisse I installed msys2 yesterday... I will check this.

Comment: Aah! I just noticed that you are using the mingw64 compiler and not the gcc installed by msys, that's probably the main difference.

Comment: MSYS2 includes a compiler, but that compiler is for an LP64 ABI. Using mingw on it is almost a cross-compilation, so it is easier to specify the platform as recommended in the accepted answer (I guess there could be ways for configure to figure out what is going on, but it is not worth the complications).

Comment: Also, msys2 lets you start a "msys2 shell" or a "mingw-w64 win64 shell", and that changes what config.guess returns on your system. I think with the second one it would just work.

Comment: @MarcGlisse That's interesting. Thanks for your analysis. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is solved by adding `--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32` to the configure command. This is generally recommended to build software that uses Autotools or some form of configure script for Windows 64-bit.

You can read [this page on the MinGW-w64 wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/TypeTriplets/) to learn more about these things. Here is the most pertinent quote from that page:

> #### Triplets and MinGW-w64
>
> When using the MinGW-w64 cross compilers, while you may need to use different `--build` triplets, you will only use the `--host` triplets `i686-w64-mingw32` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32`. Use `i686-w64-mingw32` when building for 32-bit Windows platforms, and `x86_64-w64-mingw32` when building for 64-bit Windows platforms. When using the MinGW-w64 native compilers, you typically do not need to provide `configure` any type triplet information.